# Connect windows visual studio and Mac Agent for Developing IOS in Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am developing app in cross platform using xamarin.forms. I tried to take buid for ios by connecting mac agent from windows visual studio community 2017 using windows pro OS machine. But i cant connect machine and SSH fingerprint error. i need to know can connect mac via Visual studio community 2017 for take build or any restriction for IOS development. To resolve this, are we need to use Visual studio Enterprises 2017?? pls guide me to solve this issues.

Setup Details:

- OS - Windows Pro
- Tool - Windows Visual Studio Community 2017
- Platform - Xamarin.Forms(Cross Platform)
- Mac System - Advanced Version

Comment: Can only tell from experience that you can connect to mac with Visual Studio 2017 Community, Enterprise is not needed.